# Content Iterator for list in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Do you use Content Iterator frequently on a large list in SP 2010? 
Even if threshold value is not set on a list, can we get good performance on list if query is fired through Content Iterator?

Plz reply .

Answer (score 1):

The Content Iterator is introduced to skip the query threshold. If you are not using it against the large lists, there is no place to use it. So use it.

But it is about the way and the place you use it. For example if you are using it for a page load where all the users access it, I will not recommend it. Because that could put many performance concerns on the server given the frequency of large query executing is high.

There are scenarios this will come handy. For example in a situation like timer jobs which fires once a day, this will be good to use. Given the frequency of use is lower.

So it is all about the place and the frequency of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Content Iterator on a large list. It does not give you good performance at all. It just allows you to avoid threshold limitations. for good performance you can use classic SharePoint paging and get elements page by page using SPQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition property. Here is an [example](http://sharepointweblog.blogspot.ru/2010/09/sharepoint-2010-paging-in-sharepoint.html)